# How to Save Specific Row records into separate csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, group-by

Currently, I am doing a project in which I have to fetch data of records of specific columns and save them in separate csvs. Problem is it is ok to save record of 1 or 2 records, but there are around 1500 unique records, so how can we do that using pandas in python.

For fetch data of one or two records code is

**new_df = df.loc[df['Name'].isin(['Paul', 'John', 'Andrew'])]**

So, this code will fetch values where name is paul, john,andrew and after that we can save them in separate 3 csv using to_csv function, but how can i do this for around 1500 unique names. So, please help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this:

```
unique_names = df["Name"].unique()

for name in unique_names:
    temp = df[df["Name"] == name]
    temp.to_csv(f"{name}.csv")
```